# ASP.netの発行ができない

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net

ASP.netの発行についてご教示ください。

1.プロジェクトを右クリックして発行(B)を選択すると「オブジェクト参照がオブジェクト　インスタンスに設定されていません。」とのエラーが出て先に進めません。

2.プロジェクトのプロパティを選択し、「Web のパッケージ化/発行」を選択すると以下が表示されて何もできません。
ページの読み込み中にエラーが発生しました。
a553ad0b-2f9e-4bce-95b3-9a1f7074bc27

以下、バージョン等です。
Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.4.1
Microsoft .Net Framework Version 4.7.02556
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro バージョン 10.0.16299 ビルド 16299

どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: とりあえず最新のVisual Studioに更新してみては

Comment: 最新（15.7.3）にバージョン・アップしてみましたが発行できませんでした。
他のPCにインストールした場合、発行ができたのでインストールしなおしてみます。

Comment: バージョンアップ後にインストーラーより修復をしたら発行ができるようになりました。
ありがとうございました。